# Undefined id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting undefined ids probably because of stupid syntax error somewhere. I checked to make sure the ids in question (oTel and oTel2) are not duplicated anywhere (they're only there one time)

In a js function I have:

```
var ucville = $('#oVille').val();
var uctelp = $('#oTel').val();
var uctelp2 = $('#oTel2').val();
var ucEmail = $('#oEmail').val();
```

and if do:

```
alert(ucville+"\n"+uctelp+"\n"+uctelp2+"\n"+ucEmail);
```

I get for example:

Marseille
undefined
undefined
toto@awebsite.com

Here is the html:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label>Ville</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oVille" name="fpVille" value="<?php echo $uville;?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label>Telephone 1</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oTel" name="fpTel" value="<?php echo $uctelp;?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label>Telephone 2</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oTel2" name="fpTel2" value="<?php echo $uctelp2;?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label>Email 1</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oEmail" name="fpCEmail" value="<?php  echo $ucEmail?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

I just don't see what is different for the telephone ids ?

Comment: Can you confirm the PHP values are correct? (show rendered HTML, not raw)

Comment: can you print to the HTML the values of `uville;`, `ucEmail`, `uctelp2`, `uctelp`? to ensure they are populated correctly

Comment: Yes the php values are rendered correctly. It's not a server side issue, it's really client side and for some reason jquery doesn't see these 2 ids.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in the javascript. It means that `<?php echo $uctelp;?>` print nothing. So `$uctelp` is empty.

You can check it by inspecting the DOM with the dev tools of your favorite browser.

Comment: Even when I hard-code a value in the field is comes up undefined, it's something else

Answer (score 0):

I changed the names of the ids and now they're seen (defined) whether they have values or not. This should mean that the original names exist somewhere else and were duplicated but searching everywhere I can't find where.